# OnetoOneRelatedField model details are not populating while trying to post details through APIVIew in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    place=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')



class wish(models.Model):
      created=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
      title=models.CharField(default='',null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
      wishtext=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
      address=models.OneToOneField(Address,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

serializers.py file.

```
      class WishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
          class Meta:
            model = wish
            fields = ['id','title','wishtext','address']
            depth=1
```

views.py

```
         class WishList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
         #permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
         queryset=wish.objects.all()
         serializer_class = WishSerializer
```

Note:

am able to get the all details including address model details.
But when i am trying to post details ,able to see only wish model fields but not the address object drop down field.
Please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have such behavior by overriding `create` method in your `ModelSerializer`
and put your creation logic there.

It is actually mentioned in [DRF Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) in **Writable Nested Serializers section.**, there is a good example there.

Comment: Actually, i have deleted the depth=1 from WishSerializer class and then was able to see the dropdown.  I think one more method is to override the create method.